# How do I set a breakpoint for operator() in gdb for C++?

Tags: c++, gdb, breakpoints

I have 2 methods in C++ class as follows:

```
 class myClass {
     public:
         void operator()( string myString ) {
             // Some code
         }
         void myMethod() { ... }
 }
```

For a regular method, I can simply set the breakpoint in GDB as:

```
b myClass::myMethod
```

But how do I set the breakpoint for the first method?

UPDATE:

The suggestions from initial answers (b myClass ::operator()) does not work :(

```
b myClass::operator()
Function "myClass::operator()" not defined.
```

Thanks!

Comment: UPDATE:

The suggestions from initial answers (b myClass ::operator()) does not work :(

Comment: Oh, in case it matters, gdb os version 6.4

Comment: It works for me with gdb 6.8. Perhaps you need to upgrade your gdb version.

Comment: Upgrading is not really an option, sadly - it's a large corporate environment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

gdb will also take breakpoints at specific line numbers. For example
`b file.cc:45`

Comment: I have a Class function prototyped and defined in a header file. When I do `b ClientClass.h:804`, GDB tells me `No line 804`. Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

Just the same. `myClass::operator()(string)` is a regular method.

If you have several overloaded `operator()` methods (e.g. a const and a non-const version) gdb should offer the choice where to set the breakpoint:

http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/gdb-5.0/html_node/gdb_35.html#SEC35

You may have to make sure that method `operator()(string)` is actually compiled.

**Edit:**

I've tested the following file test.cpp:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class myClass {
        public:
        void operator()( int i ) {
                std::cout << "operator()";
        }

        void myMethod() {
                std::cout << "myMethod";
        }
};

int main() {
   myClass c;
   c(1);
   c.myMethod();
   return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `g++ test.cpp -o test`, ran `gdb test` (version GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1344)), typed `start` and only then could I set breakpoints.

`b 'myClass::operator()(string)'` and

`b myClass::operator()`

both worked.

Comment: Unfortunately, the suggestions from initial answers (b myClass ::operator()) does not work - see updated Q for error :(

Answer (score 1):

Some C++ functions names can be really hard to type out correctly.  Worse yet, gdb's autocompletion often gets confused with c++ names.  I use this trick

```
gdb> break 'myClass::operator()<TAB>
```

Note the single quote at the beginning of the function.  That helps gdb's autocompleter.

Answer (score 0):

```
b myClass::operator()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the suggestions from initial answers (b myClass ::operator()) does not work - see updated Q for error :(

Comment: Works for me. I tested it before I posted this answer.

Comment: DVK -- Is your class defined inside a namespace?